# CAML statement for "top x rows" out there?

Tags: 2007, caml-query

Let's say I'm querying a big list but only need a subset of the rows for demo purposes.  What's the easiest way to say "Top 100 Rows" or similar in CAML?  Can't seem to find a statement out there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SPQuery object? If so, you can use the RowLimit property of SPQuery object.

Comment: Not quite, I'm using a SSIS Datasource component which queries from SharePoint lists.  It takes in CAML so that's feasible, but setting row limit wouldn't be (though the code is open source, a few tweaks could fix that).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `RowLimit` element.

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588460(office.11).aspx

From what I can find, it should look something like this:

```
<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">100</RowLimit>
```

Never used it myself though.